# Problem with SSL, apache2, getting 403 error when I open my website

Tags: apache2, ssl

I have a problem with the SSL certificate, although I do not know if it is the problem.

Every now and then, when I open the pixelwork.pl website, I have a 403 problem. We know how to enable indexing, it displays a list of files in the folder. Interestingly, if I refresh it already works. Every time I open pixelwork.pl for the first time on https: // I have a 403 problem.

> Log apache2: Cannot serve directory /X/X/X/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php) found ()

But `index.php` is there of course.

Comment: Is it a site or a perl script?